# Изменить код getimagesize

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить этот код, чтоб допускалось еще и пустое значение $foto, когда пользователь оставляет поле фото пустым. Сама как только не пробовала, в т.ч. через if($foto!=""), empty все равно срабатывает exit при пустом поле фото.

`$imageinfo = getimagesize($foto['tmp_name']);`

```
if ($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpg' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg')

  {
exit("<p>Такие расширения недопустимы! Можно загружать изображения в формате: gif, png, jpg, jpeg. <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О!

```
if (!empty($foto['tmp_name']) and $foto['error'] == 0 ) {..
```

Или же если я ошибся и адрес берется из БД:

```
if(!empty($foto['tmp_name'])) {...
```

А можно еще и файл проверить, существует ли он, или нет:

```
if(file_exists($foto['tmp_name'])) {...
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Как, оказывается, все просто)